# Excel formula to find all of text within text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, find

I am trying to find text within a text, and display it in a cell.

I am able to find the text like so:

=MID(A2, FIND(":",A2)+1, FIND("/", A2, FIND(":",A2)+1) - FIND(":",A2)-1)

However, I have multiple intances where there are multiple string within that cell with values meeting that condition. for example:

this is just an example :12345678/, another example
:23455663/.

My question would be, how can I capture all those values starting with ":" and finishing with "/" and not just the first intance?

additionally, if possible how can I separate each value with a line in between strings.

Comment: If you have a long term need for text searches like this, then consider learning how to use VBA, which support regular expressions.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have been using VBA, I just though a quick formula was enough to get the desired result. However, as you mentioned, VBA may be the answer to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function FindAllText(s As String)
    Dim KaptureMode As Boolean, c As String
    Dim L As Long, i As Long, CH As String
    KaptureMode = False
    c = Chr(10)
    L = Len(s)
    For i = 1 To L
        CH = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If KaptureMode Then
            If CH = "/" Then
                KaptureMode = False
                FindAllText = FindAllText & c
            Else
                FindAllText = FindAllText & CH
            End If
        Else
            If CH = ":" Then
                KaptureMode = True
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    If Right(FindAllText, 1) = c Then FindAllText = Mid(FindAllText, 1, Len(FindAllText) - 1)
End Function
```

[image]

Just be sure to format the cell with the UDF with Wrap on.

**EDIT#1:**

This version will check for an un-match **/** near the end of the string:

```
Public Function FindAllText(s As String)
    Dim KaptureMode As Boolean, c As String
    Dim L As Long, i As Long, CH As String
    Dim Candidate As String

    Candidate = ""
    KaptureMode = False
    c = Chr(10)
    L = Len(s)
    For i = 1 To L
        CH = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If KaptureMode Then
            If CH = "/" Then
                KaptureMode = False
                FindAllText = FindAllText & Candidate & c
                Candidate = ""
            Else
                Candidate = Candidate & CH
            End If
        Else
            If CH = ":" Then
                KaptureMode = True
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    If Right(FindAllText, 1) = c Then FindAllText = Mid(FindAllText, 1, Len(FindAllText) - 1)
End Function
```

[image]

As you see, **abc** does not appear in the output.

Comment: This worked flawlessly, thank you so much Gary! Brilliant!

Comment: Gary, I do have another question, related to your code. In the event that there is anothe ":" found in the document that does not meet the same condition. Example, starts with ":" but does not ends with "/". will it copy the information as well? I dont want that to happen, and wanted to verify first.

Comment: @CaptKenpa  See my **EDIT#1**